# Haskell 'show' function in second to last line not working correctly for the new variant of type 'GamePos'

Tags: haskell

The program contains a fragment of type definitions that can be used in a program for playing noughts and crosses (also known as tic-tac-toe). There's a definition of a type of “position” records, each of which is meant to represent a state of the game, i.e. the board state as well as information on whose turn it is next.

I need to add a new definition of function show to work correctly for the new variant of type
'GamePos'. The data type GamePos supports two variants.

Please feel free to ask any questions so I can elaborate on my problem.

```
data GamePos 
    = GamePos
      {
        pos_board :: Board,
        pos_turn :: Player,
        pos_value :: Float
      } 
      | GamePosWin
      {
        pos_board :: Board,
        pos_turn :: Player,
        pos_value :: Float
      }
    deriving (Eq)

instance (Show GamePos) where
    show (GamePos board turn value) =
        unlines -- put the following strings on separate lines
        [show board, 
         "Player to take next move: " ++ show turn, 
         "Estimated advantage of player X against player O: " ++ show value] 
    show (GamePosWin board turn value) =
        unlines
        [show board,
         "Player won: " ++ show turn]

gamePos1 =
    GamePos board Player_X 0
        where
        board = 
            Board
            [[X,X,O],
             [O,B,X],
             [O,B,B]]
  
gamePos1B =
    GamePos board Player_O 0
        where
        board = 
            Board
            [[X,X,O],
             [O,B,X],
             [O,B,B]]
  

gamePos2 = 
    GamePosWin board Player_X
        where
        board = 
            Board
            [[X,X,O],
             [O,X,X],
             [O,O,X]]


main =
    do
    putStr "equalBoards (gamePos1, gamePos1B) = "
    putStrLn $ show $ equalBoards (gamePos1, gamePos1B)
    putStrLn "gamePos1 = "
    putStrLn $ show gamePos1
    putStrLn "gamePos2 = "
    putStrLn $ show gamePos2
         

equalBoards (pos1, pos2) = (pos_board pos1 == pos_board pos2)
```

Comment: I take by "variant" you mean "constructor".

Comment: `gamePos2` is a function so the line `putStrLn $ show gamePos2` should not compile, since you can't show functions. You should add `pos_value` to `gamePos2 ` construction: `GamePosWin board Player_X 0`

Comment: Likely @lsmor cracked the case. Keep in mind if you get compilation errors it's very helpful copy and paste them in the question.

Comment: @lsmor Thank you. If gamePos1 is also a function, how is that able to compile?

Comment: gamePos1 is not a function since you supplied 3 arguments to `GamePos`.  gamePos2 is a function because the constructor used requires 3 arguments and you gave it 2.

Comment: Please include youre error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your definition of `gamePos2`, you have only specified two arguments:

```
gamePos2 = 
    GamePosWin board Player_X
        where
        board = 
            Board
            [[X,X,O],
             [O,X,X],
             [O,O,X]]
```

However, that constructor takes three arguments based on its definition:

```
GamePosWin
      {
        pos_board :: Board,
        pos_turn :: Player,
        pos_value :: Float
      }
```

You need to either remove the `pos_value` argument from the `GamePosWin` constructor, or provide a third argument to the constructor. As-is, the type of `gamePos2` is `Float -> GamePos`, and there is no `Show` instance for functions.